# How to stay in the same page when we use jquery load

Tags: jquery, html

this is my example file:

```
<html >
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#hr').click(function() {
$('#main').load('show.php'); 
});
})
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="hr"></div>
<div id="main"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

in the show.php file i have a submit button , so when i load the file in a div , when i click the submit button it take me to the home page , i mean the div where i load the show.php file disappear, what i want is when i click the submit button i don't want anything to change in the page.

Answer (score 0):

You will need the submit button to `return false`, e.g.:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="doStuff(); return false;" />
```

Comment: but when i do like that it doesn't do anything

Comment: if i do what you say it doesn't submit the form.